# Object Disposed Exception when calling context from base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I currently have this setup

repository A has baseclass B
repository A gets a DBContext
Repository A passes DBContext to its baseClass B
B tries to use said context to modify and save values (with saveValuesAsync())
However, when i try to use the context in the base class System.ObjectDisposedException

```
  public ARepository(
     ExDBcontext context,
   ):base (context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }
```

And repository B

```
    private readonly exDbContext _context;
    public TagsRepository(exDbContext context)
    {
       _context =  context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

    }
    public async Task  someMethod () 
    {
        // change values 
        _context.ValuesEx.Add(t);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // gives error 
      
    }
```

I'm kind of at a loss, so maybe the question isn't up to par and more information is necessary, but I hope it explains enough.

Comment: You should simply debug the ExDBContext (for example put a breakpoint into its dispose method) and see yourself why its gets disposed and by whom.

Comment: The specifics for this exception will depend entirely on your actual implementation. You need to show your actual code or a minimal example that actually reproduces the issue for you.  Depending on where the DbContext is actually instantiated (A IoC Container or passed in from within a `using` block, something as simple as forgetting to `await` a method in the call stack could see the DbContext disposed.